# Material UI importing filter function into <AutoComplete filter= />

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Not sure if it's a bug or my react knowledge is lacking. I get no errors, but filter doesn't work. If I write function into same file, the filter works, am I doing something wrong ?

**Filters.js**

```
const filterResults = (searchText, key) => {
 if (searchText.length === 0) {
   return false;
 }
  const compareString = key.toLowerCase();
  searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

  const subMatchKey = key.substring(0, searchText.length);
 const distance = AutoComplete.levenshteinDistance(searchText.toLowerCase(), subMatchKey.toLowerCase());
  let searchTextIndex = 0;
  for (let index = 0; index < key.length; index++) {
    if (compareString[index] === searchText[searchTextIndex]) {
      searchTextIndex += 1;
    }
  }

  return searchText.length > 3 ? distance < 2 : distance === 0;
  return searchTextIndex === searchText.length;
 };

 export default filterResults;
```

**Main.js**

```
import filterResults from '../AutoComplete/Filters'

    <AutoComplete
        dataSource={location}
        onUpdateInput={this.onInputChange}
        searchText={this.state.city}
        filter={this.filterResults}

      />
```

Comment: You shouldn't use "this." on filter={this.filterResults}, as its not a member of your component.

Comment: Still doesn't work as intended. Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoComplete is not defined

Comment: You need to also add "import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';" to your Filters.js file, since you are referencing a static method on it here: "const distance = AutoComplete.levenshteinDistance(...)..."

Comment: Worked, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
<AutoComplete
    dataSource={location}
    filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
  />
```

Material-UI has a few built in filtering functions